# Math::BigInt: not expected result in making two consecutive arithmetic operations

Tags: perl, operators, bigint

I'm trying to hold two consecutive operations `$x->badd(1)` and `$x->bmuladd(2,-1)` using  `Math::BigInt` as shown in the code below:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Math::BigInt;

my $k = '1329227995784915872903807060280344577'; 
my $x = Math::BigInt->new($k);

my $y = $x->badd(1);
my $z = $x->bmuladd(2,-1);


print "value to variable z $z\n";

print "value to variable y is $y\n";
```

But I do not understand the reason for output to be as shown below:

```
value to variable z 2658455991569831745807614120560689155
value to variable y is 2658455991569831745807614120560689155
```

instead of:

```
value to variable z 2658455991569831745807614120560689153
value to variable y is 1329227995784915872903807060280344578
```

I can only get the value of the variable `$z` or `$y` if I do from one of two forms below respectively:

1)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Math::BigInt;

my $k = '1329227995784915872903807060280344577'; 
my $x = Math::BigInt->new($k);

#my $y = $x->badd(1);
my $z = $x->bmuladd(2,-1);


print "value to variable z $z\n";

#print "value to variable y is $y\n";
```

or ...

2)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Math::BigInt;

my $k = '1329227995784915872903807060280344577'; 
my $x = Math::BigInt->new($k);

my $y = $x->badd(1);
#my $z = $x->bmuladd(2,-1);


#print "value to variable z $z\n";

print "value to variable y is $y\n";
```

What am I doing wrong or what am I not doing?

**EDIT UPDATE:**

I believe that I need to understand the operation of the values of the variables (that is, I believe that `$x` remains with the result of the first operation and it is necessary to use `$x->bsub(1)` to return to its original state) because doing as below I was able to get the expected result:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Math::BigInt;

my $k = '1329227995784915872903807060280344577'; 
my $x = Math::BigInt->new($k);

my $y = $x->badd(1);

print "value to variable y is $y\n";

my $u = $y->bsub(1);

my $z = $u->bmuladd(2,-1);

print "value to variable z $z\n";
```

Though ... if I put `print "value to variable y is $y\n";` the last line, as shown below, then returned not to have the expected result:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Math::BigInt;

my $k = '1329227995784915872903807060280344577'; 
my $x = Math::BigInt->new($k);

my $y = $x->badd(1);


my $u = $y->bsub(1);

my $z = $u->bmuladd(2,-1);

print "value to variable y is $y\n";

print "value to variable z $z\n";
```